# PHP mysql while not assigning variables in correspondence to the database key

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

so this was working perfect up until an hour ago and since then i have racked my brain to fix it and got nothing, maybe im missing the obvious (thats usually the case).

The code prints out a list of users and a button to ban them in a table, however the problem is if you click ban on say.. the 34th user it bans the first, then if you click ban on the 56th user it bans the second user. If you see my code you should see that that shouldn't be the case (note all other details are perfectly right except for the uID):

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, full_name, banned, username from `tblUsers`");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $uID = $row['id'];
            if($row['banned'] == '0'){ 
                $banBool =  '<form id="ban" method="post" action="ban.php?uid='.$uID.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="ban" value="" /> 
            <a onclick="document.getElementById(\'ban\').submit();">Ban</a>
        </form>'; }else{   
            $banBool = '<form id="unban" method="post" action="unban.php?uid='.$uID.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="" /> 
            <a onclick="document.getElementById(\'unban\').submit();">UnBan</a>
            </form>' ;
        }
            if($row['banned'] == '1'){
                $status = 'Banned';
            }else{
                $status = 'Active';
            }
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['username'] . " " . $uID . "</td><td>" . $banBool . "</td><td>" . $status . "</td><td>" . $row['full_name'] . "</td></tr>";
        }
```

The issue is in the action="unban.php?uid='.$uID.' as when i trace the path the id is always the lowest number (top result)

ban.php

```
<?php
include '../../includes/dataBase.class.php';
sql::connect();
if(!sql::checkAdmin() == 1){
    header("Location: ../myaccount.php");
}
if(!isset($_GET['uid'])){
    header("Location: users.php?action=1");
}
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `uipBan` (`ip`) VALUES ('$ip')")or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("UPDATE tblUsers SET banned = '1' WHERE id = '$uid'")or die(mysql_error());
//header("Location: users.php?action=1");
echo $uid;
?>
```

Comment: What's the point of your hidden inputs? Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: The hidden input just makes it a "button" but looks like a hyperlink thats all. This is the output http://i40.tinypic.com/2wqua07.jpg ignore the juy that was just some debug stuff, the number next to the name is the id from the db of each account

Comment: In fact, what's the point of the forms, even? Can't you just generate links directly? You seem to be using a mixture of GET and POST requests, that's bound to cause some trouble :)

Comment: @Daan check my OP i have updated it with ban.php ;-)I am using post as when i set the method to get nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provide a form for each user which bans/unbans that user.  The problem is in your form `id` because they're not unique.  When you click on any `Ban`/`UnBan` link, JavaScript searches for the `ban`/`unban` element, finds the first one and submits that one.

The solution is very easy:

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, full_name, banned, username from `tblUsers`");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $uID = $row['id'];
            if($row['banned'] == '0'){ 
                $banBool =  '<form id="ban' . $uID . '" method="post" action="ban.php?uid='.$uID.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="ban" value="" /> 
            <a onclick="document.getElementById(\'ban' . $uID . '\').submit();">Ban</a>
        </form>'; }else{   
            $banBool = '<form id="unban' . $uID . '" method="post" action="unban.php?uid='.$uID.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="unban" value="" /> 
            <a onclick="document.getElementById(\'unban' . $uID . '\').submit();">UnBan</a>
            </form>' ;
        }
            if($row['banned'] == '1'){
                $status = 'Banned';
            }else{
                $status = 'Active';
            }
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['username'] . " " . $uID . "</td><td>" . $banBool . "</td><td>" . $status . "</td><td>" . $row['full_name'] . "</td></tr>";
        }
```

I just included the User ID on every form and JS call so that they are unique.  (Also, your second hidden field had the name as `name`)

Comment: Wow thank you! Im sure i didnt have it like that before when it worked, your a star thank you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @MrFusion nailed it (+1). But I still don't see why you aren't simply doing something like this:

```
 <?php
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, full_name, banned, username from `tblUsers`");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

      echo "<tr><td>{$row['username']}</td><td>{$row['id']}</td>";

      if($row['banned'] == '0') { 
           echo "<td><a href=\"admin.php?ban={$row['id']}\">Ban</a></td>";
      }
      elseif($row['banned'] == '1') { 
            echo "<td>Banned (<a href=\"admin.php?unban={$row['id']}\">Unban</a>)</td>";
      }
      else { 
           echo "<td>Active</td>"; # Not sure what this is for in your original code
      }
      echo "<td>{$row['full_name']}</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Then just make admin.php

```
<?php
include "../../includes/dataBase.class.php";
sql::connect();
if(!sql::checkAdmin() == 1){
    header("Location: ../myaccount.php");
}
if(!isset($_GET['ban']) AND !isset($_GET['unban'])){
    header("Location: users.php?action=1");
}

if(isset($_GET['ban'])) { 
    $uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ban']);
    mysql_query("UPDATE tblUsers SET banned = '1' WHERE id = '{$uid}'") or die(mysql_error());    
    //I don't know what the following two lines are for
    //but they seem to IP-ban the admin himself: you're banning the IP address 
    //of the user doing the ban, not the IP address of the user you are banning. 

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `uipBan` (`ip`) VALUES ('{$ip}')") or die(mysql_error()); 
}
elseif(isset($_GET['unban'])) { 
    $uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['unban']);
    mysql_query("UPDATE tblUsers SET banned = '0' WHERE id = '{$uid}'") or die(mysql_error());        
} 

header("Location: users.php?action=1");
?>
```

Note the importance of escaping your user input using mysql_real_escape_string, even if it's coming from a trusted user: this prevents SQL injection which could result in you losing your entire database :)